# Should OGR2Layers plug-in respect layer transparency?

Tags: qgis, ogr2layers

When I export a graduated style layer from QGIS Dufour to OpenLayers using the OGR2Layers plug-in and QGIS rendering the colors and categories come across correctly. However, the opacity in the HTML is set to 1, where it should be .3 in my example . Am I doing something wrong, or does OGR2Layers not handle transparency? It's easy enough to edit the transparency in the HTML, but if there's a direct way, that would be nice.

Comment: Exactly what kind of layer?

Comment: A polygon vector layer, specifically a shapefile.

Comment: I've never used this plugin, but from review of the source code, the transparency stuff is still in work. https://github.com/lucadelu/OGR2Layers/blob/master/OGR2ClassStyle.py#L55 is in the except code path, and you'd need version=2 to get to the classes that actually do opacity. Maybe you could hack the code?

Comment: Do try qgis2web, which might fare better.